# Frama-C Plugin: Calling !Db.Value.compute() and hide output

Tags: frama-c

Is it possible to hide the output when calling `!Db.Value.compute()` in a Frama-C plugin? I didn't find a corresponding function.

Can I do it somehow by a command-line parameter? (Which is then somehow automatically set for my call?)

Comment: You should have a look at `frama-c -value-help`. The `OUTPUT MESSAGES` section provides a lot of options to enable/disable printing different things.

Comment: `Db.Value.compute` prints the same messages as those emitted by the Value plugin (`-val`), because that's the function actually called by the plugin, hence Anne's indication. Some relevant options you should take a look at are `-val-show-progress`, `-val-show-initial-state`, `-val-print`, or even `-value-verbose 0` (but then you may also miss some important messages).

Comment: Oh, ok. I didn't know that the command-line parameters are also used, if the use of the value-analysis isn't specified in in commandline, but in another plugin. (I thought I have to specify it in my plugin). 
Thanks for the fast response, problem solved :)